# Is it possible to set a variable via its own setter method?

Tags: swift

As I am going through the Swift Language Guide, I am trying to see whether I can implement a Struct that will have a width property which will include a getter/setter that will get/set its own value. Is that possible? Example:

```
struct Resolution {
    static var standardResWidth = 1024
    var height = 0
    var width: Int {
        get {
            return self.width;
        }
        set {
            if newValue > Resolution.standardResWidth {
                width = newValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By the look of things, the compiler of Playground throws an error on this one. As soon as I make a separate variable though, it works:

```
struct Resolution {
    static var standardResWidth = 1024
    var height = 0
    var width = 0
    var setWidth: Int {
        get {
            return width;
        }
        set {
            if newValue > Resolution.standardResWidth {
                width = newValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: some runtime thing, "execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code =2.. address=0x....)

Comment: I just realized it's a duplicate - I found my answer elsewhere.